# Store previous rows details in a list of dictionary in Dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

Store previous rows details in a list of dictionary in Dataframe.
DataFrame is like

```
df:
Rows    Alphabet    Count
r1      a           1
r2      a           2
r3      b           1
r4      a           3
r5      b           2
```

Is it possible that Output should be like

```
df:
Rows    Alphabet    Count   countDetails
r1      a           1       [{id:a,count:1}]
r2      a           2       [{id:a,count:2}]
r3      b           1       [{id:a,count:2},{id:b,count:1}]
r4      a           3       [{id:a,count:3},{id:b,count:1}]
r5      b           2       [{id:a,count:3},{id:b,count:2}]
```

It should store the number of alphabet came till that row and count of each alphabet.
Like till r3 only 'a' was there and in r3 alphabet 'b' came so it should store count of 'a' and 'b'

Comment: What are the possible values of the Alphabet column? The entire a-z?

Comment: yes entire a-z. its just an example it may be anything 1-100 or 1-1000 like this.
it it possible to store like this.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df['countDetails'] = ''

count_dict = {}

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    count_dict.setdefault(row['Alphabets'], 0)
    count_dict[row['Alphabets']] = row['Count']
    k= map(lambda x:{'id':x,'count':count_dict[x]}, count_dict)

    df.at[ index, 'countDetails'] = k
```

Comment: I have modified the solution little bit, please go through it if you would have time.

Comment: Welcome dude! If the answer has solved the issue, do mark it as 'correct answer'! You can check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Just suggesting as you seem to be a new user.

Comment: @AbhijitGhate : Great!! You can replace lines 9-14 to just `k= map(lambda x:{'id':x, 'count':count_dict[x]}, count_dict)`

Comment: @AmarKamthe yeah, that's neater